# I get a 404 on a laravel app running on Nginx

Tags: laravel, nginx

I have this nginx config.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name apps.myapp.com;

        root /var/www/apps.myapp.com/public;
        index index.php;

        location / {
                 try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?$query_string;
        }
}
```

I have this route:

```
Route::get('/lead', 'LeadsController@index' );
```

When I access to `http://apps.myapp.com/lead`, I get 404.

Comment: try to change your location to `location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 redirect;
    }
    if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can run `nginx -t` to check if there any error in the file configuration, in addition to that you need to add `fastcgi_pass`

Below is nginx configuration from my production server

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/laravel/public/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

     location ~ \.php$ {
         try_files $uri /index.php =404;
         fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_index index.php;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         include fastcgi_params;
     }
}
```

You can read this tutorial is very helpful:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-in-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0):

This is the configuration I use for my Laravel app.

```
location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
}
```